# Table Decorators on Zend Framework Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, zend-form-element

i created a form that it decorates as table form

its my code for decorates

```
$this->setElementDecorators(array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Errors'
            array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'),
            array('tag'=>'td','class'=>'element')),
            array('Label',array('tag'=>'td')),
            array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr')),

    ));

$this->setDecorators(array(
            'FormElements',
            array('HtmlTag',array('tag'=>'table')),
            'Form'
        ));
```

it works correctly,
now i wana errors message decorates too
what do i change  my code?

Comment: I can't edit your code since I don't have enough reputation.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a rather complex way of doing it. I have added classes to the decorators too so you can style them unlike your example.

```
// To be assigned at the beginning of your form class.

    public $elementDecorators = array(
    'ViewHelper',
    'Errors',
    array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'class' => 'col2')),
    array('Label', array('tag' => 'td','class'=>'taR')),
    array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr','class' => 'rowA')),
    );

$this->addElement('ValidationTextBox', 'name', array(
            'decorators' => $this->elementDecorators,
            'validators' => array(                                 
                                array('regex',  false,'/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/')
                            ),
            'label' => $this->translator->translate ( 'Name' ) . ' : ',
            'required' => true,
            'trim' => true,
            'propercase' => true,
             'regExp' => '[a-zA-Z ]+',
                'invalidMessage' => $this->translator->translate ( 'Name - Must be alpha numeric.' )
            )
            );
```

Comment: i want error message is displayed beside elements not under them, how can i  decorates them

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show all erros grouped in one place you should remove the Error decorator from each element and then add to you form the formErrors decorator. Here is an example from [How to remove Zend Form error messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065903/how-to-remove-zend-form-error-messages)

```
$form->setDecorators(array(
    'FormElements',
    new Zend_Form_Decorator_FormErrors(array
        (
            'ignoreSubForms' => true,
            'markupElementLabelEnd' => '</b>',
            'markupElementLabelStart' => '<b>',
            'markupListEnd' => '</div>',
            'markupListItemEnd' => '</span>',
            'markupListItemStart' => '<span>',
            'markupListStart' => '<div id="Form_Errors">'
        )
    ),
    'Form'
));
```